# id is different for Chrome and Vivaldi?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, vivaldi

After installing of my extension on Vivaldi browser I found that id (origin) is not the same as for Chrome. This is expected behaviour?

[image: request headers chrome extension origin]

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "short_name": "Intelligent Speaker",
    "name": "Text to speech that brings productivity",
    "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
    "homepage_url": "https://intelligent-speaker.com",
    "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; img-src *; media-src https://intelligent-speaker.com https://intelligentspeaker.s3.amazonaws.com blob:; connect-src https://intelligentspeaker.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com https://intelligent-speaker.com/voice-preview/ https://mjqj47yt17.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com https://api.intelligent-speaker.com https://intelligentspeaker.s3.amazonaws.com; style-src https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com/;",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus"
    ],
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "version": "2018.10.12.1214",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "128": "images/logo/logo128.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "images/logo/logo128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "page": "eventPage.html",
        "persistent": false
    },
    "author": "Intelligent Speaker",
    "incognito": "not_allowed",
    "container": "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "60"
}
```

Comment: 1) could be a bug in Vivaldi, 2) or if you install it locally as an unpacked extension from a different folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addon is loaded as an addon with a temporary id. This means the browser gets to decide the addon ID since you didn't specify one. That's why you end up with different temporary addon ids (it should be random for security.)

In Firefox, you can specify an addon ID like this:

```
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "addonid@domain.org"
    }
}
```

But still, the internal id might be used for Origin headers and file URLs. Don't worry about it, it's done for security.

Comment: But what about Chrome - `id` (origin) changed after every extension update (publish)?

Comment: If it's a local development environment, that's expected. If published in the Chrome Webstore I would expect it to keep the same id throughout updates.